# How to use multiple tables to get the data in JDBC connectivity?

Tags: sql, jdbc, ojdbc

Hello I am writing a query in `SQL` that gets data from multiple tables and in retrieving data from resultset, we need to do `rs.getString(1)` from the corresponding table, but for me the data comes from multiple tables.

Can you let me know how to do it?

For easy reference I am including my `SQL` query

```
select EID,sport,emich_email, lastname,firstname,numtodsinterval(sum(
  extract(day from dd) * (24 * 60 * 60)
    + extract(hour from dd) * (60 * 60)
    + extract(minute from dd) * 60
    + extract(second from dd)
  ), 'SECOND') as total_hours
from (
  select scans.emich_email,EID,lastname,firstname,Sport, sign_out - sign_in as dd from scans INNER JOIN student_details ON scans.emich_email=student_details.emich_email INNER JOIN Athlete ON student_details.EID=Athlete.EID)
group by emich_email,EID,lastname,firstname,sport;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to recover the columns with an alias, like in

```
select name as the_name, surname as the_surname from employees where...
```

and then recover each column from your `ResultSet` by its alias

```
String myName = rs.getString("the_name");
String mySurname = rs.getString("the_surname");
...
```

If you choose carefully your alias, you could try this:

```
select table1.xxx as table1_xxx, table1.yyy as table1_yyy, ...., table3.zzz as table3_zzz from table1 join table2 on ...
```

I don't know if this is what you need, but maybe this can be useful to you or at least a bit more readable java code